# Can I sell library which uses QtWebKit?

Tags: qt, qt4, licensing

I want to use QtWebKit, which uses QtCore and QtGui DLLs. Can I sell a library which uses them and redistribute them with my library's instalation? The library is not open source.

Comment: I'm voting to close as Too Localized as legal advice this specific is probably better handled through other channels.

Comment: There are plenty of questions about that here. But no one telling about a library.

Comment: http://qt.nokia.com/products/licensing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt is under the LGPL version 2.1, so, yes, you can sell a library and distribute the Qt library with it, provided that when you distribute your library, you "give prominent notice with each copy" that Qt is used and that Qt is covered by the LGPL.

This same rule applies to both applications and libraries that use Qt, as long as they are not derivative works, and if you do make any changes within Qt's code that those changes are published under the terms of the LGPL.

Answer (score 0):

Licensing information for QTWebKit can be found at http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtwebkit.html#license-information.

Agree question s/b closed - this isn't the right place for legal advice.

Comment: Yeah, it should be closed. Although it was useful for me to brush up on my knowledge of what the LGPL actually states.